# creating stack chart using categorical data

Tags: python, pandas, charts

I am going to design a stacked bar chart using the categorical data in this data frame:

```
   gender     distress
    female     high
    male       low
    female     high
    male       high
    male      medium
    female    high
    male       medium
    male      medium
    female     low
```

I know that I can filter the data based on gender and then counts the distress and then draw the stacked chart. Is there a faster way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First using `crosstab`, then `plot`

```
pd.crosstab(df.gender,df.distress).plot(kind='bar',stacked=True)
```

Comment: Thank you Wen-Ben. Do you know how to use percentage to draw the Stacked Chart?

Comment: @Mary `pd.crosstab(df.gender,df.distress,normalize ='index').plot(kind='bar',stacked=True)`